# Can we find a holomorphic function $f$ on an annulus such that $e^{f(z)}=z$

Tags: complex-analysis, rouches-theorem

Can we find a holomorphic function $f$ on an annulus $A$ such that $\exp(f(z)) = z$ for all $z$ in $A$, where $A = {z:1/2<|z|<1}$.
I guess that we should apply the argument principle or Rouche theorem, but I don't know how to. Could someone give an explicit answer?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2151918/42969